# JavaFX inhibit Property change in Listener

Tags: validation, properties, javafx, changelistener

I want to implement field validation on JavaFX controls.
My strategy is to add a ChangeListener to the relevant Property in the control.

This works quite well to *detect* teh errors, but I didn't find any way to *prevent* them.

When ChangeListener is called is too late (Property was already changed) and "reverting" it in code fires another event clearing the error flag.

Is there a way to achieve this?